# Building third-party libraries during the build process

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have a project with the following structure

```
+--foo/
   |
   +-- CMakeLists.txt
   +-- src/
   +-- include/
   +-- third-party/
       |
       +-- thing.tar.gz
```

An step of the build process is to inflate and untar `thing.tar.gz`, build it using CMake, and once that is ready proceed to compile and link whatever is under `src` (my actual project).

I would like all of this to be done *out of source*, in a `build` directory. Ultimately I would like my build process to be as follows:

```
$ cd /path/to/where/I/want/to/build/
$ cmake /path/to/directory/containing/CMakeFiles.txt/
$ make
# make inflates, untars, and builds thing.tar.gz
$ ls
# lists all the CMake stuff and the following folders:
# bin/ -> with all my application AND thing.tar.gz executables
# lib/ -> with all my libraries AND thing.tar.gz libraries
# include/ -> with all my headers AND thing.tar.gz headers
```

For the life of me, I cannot find a simple solution! So far, I am able to rely on `EXECUTE_PROCESS` to extract to a folder in the build tree, but I cannot call CMake on the resulting library, or to inform the rest of my project *hey, I extracted and built your dependencies [here] and [there]; you can carry on building now*.

How would you address this problem?

Comment: [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) should build 3d-party library gracefully. In any case, **show your code**, which doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't have code past EXECUTE_PROCESS (which correctly extracts into the build directory) because every solution I've found online seems so very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=` to point cmake to where your dependencies' build artifacts are installed to during your own project's `cmake` invocation.